# Time delay between futures in Play framework 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, future, timedelay

I have a number of consuming works that are fully asynchronous and started roughly at the same time. I mean something like this:

```
for (i <- 1 to n) {
  Future { startWork("work" + i) }
}
```

But I need to add some time lag to start these works successively at the different time. For example, if (time lag = 1 second) => i-work starts after i seconds. How can simply do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The code actually won't start all of them at the same time.  It will schedule them.  It is then up to the `ExecutionContext` to decide when they should actually run.  So maybe you need a custom `ExecutionContext` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to configure a custom `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: This link should get you on the right path for configuring a custom ExecutionContext: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ThreadPools

Answer (score 1):

Play integrates Akka for scheduling. [In Play's documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAkka), you can find an example for running a block of code once with a set delay:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) {
    file.delete()
}
```

[Akka's documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/scheduler.html) has some more info on its scheduler.
The argument (`10.seconds`) in the example is a `FiniteDuration`, so in your case, you'd probably want to set it to `i seconds`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo Dawg! I heard you like Futures, so I'm going to show you how to execute a Future in the future so you can compose other Futures from your Future in the future.

```
import play.api.concurrent.Akka
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val promise = Promise[Unit]
Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1.seconds) { promise.success() }
promise.future.map { _ => /* The body of the Future to be run in the future */ }
```

This should be a non-blocking solution do delay the execution of a Future until some time in the future.